# Powershell:Webclient is failing to upload string

Tags: python, powershell, curl

My https POST request works using curl on UNIX with python using the following command:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(['curl','-s','-k','-X','POST', '-H','Content-Type: application/json','-d',message,<https link>],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

It can send any string to the web server. Now, I would like have the same on Windows using powershell. I have done the following:

```
$webclient = new-object system.net.webclient;
$webclient.UploadString("https://host/message","string in json format");
```

However, it failed:

```
Exception calling "UploadString" with "2" argument(s): "The underlying connection was     closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."
At line:1 char:24
+ $webclient.UploadString <<<< ("https://host/message","strng in json format");
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Is there somethign am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Joie

Comment: Hi all, I made it to work by adding: [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}   Could anyone have a good tutorial about this class? Thanks!

Comment: Hi all, I changed the value of   [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback   to FALSE but the error still gone. Is this normal ? Also, I checked the msdn site about  ServerCertificateValidationCallback and it says, Gets or sets the callback to validate a server certificate. I dont really see the point..Could anyone clarify ? Thanks again!

Comment: I have a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683577/powershell-v2-uploadstring-never-connect

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Invoke-RestMethod?

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://host/message" -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body '{"string in json format"}'
```